# Recursively checking if all elements in a list are a certain value in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I have defined it as follows in Prolog:

```
listOfa([H|T]):- H = 'a', listOfa(T).
listOfa([]).
```

It does what I want it to do. It checks if all items in a list are a certain element, in this case the character `a`, and returns true or false accordingly. However, it returns true if the list is empty, and I don't want it to. Except, I'm not sure what to use as a base case for the recursion besides the empty list. How do I maintain the recursion without it returning true for an empty list?

Comment: Your base case could be `listOfa([a])` instead of `listOfa([])`.

Comment: Also, change `H` to `a` and get rid of the unification on the next step, it's more work than you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is natural to start with two clauses for empty and non-empty lists, and in fact you can keep this pattern! You can easily solve this with a *separate* predicate that is true iff its argument is a list with at least one element.

For example:

```
not_empty([_|_]).
```

Then, post the **conjunction** of this predicate and that which you have already successfully implemented.

If you want, you can also combine this into a third predicate that consists only of this conjunction.

Also, check this out:

```
?- maplist(=(a), Ls).
```

After combining these goals, you can—by purely algebraic resoning—find an even shorter solution!

Comment: `listOfA([a|T]) :- maplist(=(a), T).` :)

Comment: @DanielLyons Could you explain why `listOfA([a|T]) :- maplist(=(a), T).` returns `true.` while debugging, but `listOfa([a|T]):- a = 'a', listOfa(T).`
`listOfa([a]).` returns `true` (no period)? What is the program doing differently in the two cases?